# Извлечь дату из строки и узнать день недели

Tags: python, строки, парсер, дата

Имеется строка:

```
name = 'Замена_на_14_декабря_2019_г..docx'
```

Необходимо извлечь дату и узнать какой это день недели

В интернете нашел только извлечение формата 00/00/00

Comment: 1. Чтобы в Python выполнить поиск в строке, используют метод find(str)
2. Метод list(str)
3. https://python-scripts.com/datetime-time-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `dateutil`:

```
import re
import locale
from dateutil import parser

name = 'Замена_на_14_December_2019_г..docx'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru')
extr_date = re.search("(\d+.+?)_г", name).group(1).replace("_"," ")
print(extr_date)
print(parser.parse(extr_date).weekday()+1)
print(parser.parse(extr_date).strftime("%A"))
```

получим извлеченную дату в строковом виде, порядковый номер дня недели (+1 там потому что по умолчанию первым днем недели считается воскресенье) и название дня недели:

```
14 December 2019
6
суббота
```